# Do we use compact for $\textbf{sets}$ or for $\textbf{spaces}$?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces, definition

Before stating my questions, let me first state my understandings. Note this post is talking on metric spaces case. For the definition of a set $E$ being **open** in a metric space $(X,d)$, we mean that for every $a\in E$, there exists a ball $B(a,r)=\{x\in X|d(x,a)<r\}$ such that $B(a,r)\subseteq E$. Notice that the ball in the definition is with respect to $(X,d)$ (the ball centered at point $a$ and consist of all point in $X$ such that $d(x,a)<r$), it is quite important. Since every subset of a metric space is always a metric subspace; and every metric subspace is open in itself, by trivial reason. If we consider $E\subseteq X$ to be a metric space, then $E$ is always open in $(E,d)$.

For example, $[0,1]$ is not open in $(\mathbb{R},d)$; however, $[0,1]$ is open in $([0,1],d)$. So what metric space the set $E$ is with respect to play an important role when talking whether the set $E$ is open.

Now go to the definition of **compactness**, and also **sequentially compact**.
It has two variations the definition would make:

(For $\textbf{compactness}$)

1. Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space, let $E\subseteq X$, if every open covering $\mathcal{A}$ of $E$ contains a finite subcollection that also covers $E$, then $E$ is called a $\textbf{compact set}$.
2. Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. If every open covering $\mathcal{A}$ of $X$ contains a finite subcollection that also covers $X$, then $X$ is called a $\textbf{compact metric space}$.

(For $\textbf{sequentially compactess}$)

1. Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space, let $E\subseteq X$, if every sequence of points of $E$ has a convergent subsequence, then $E$ is called a $\textbf{sequentially compact set}$.
2. Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. If every sequence of points of $X$ has a convergent subsequence, then $X$ is called a $\textbf{sequentially compact metric space}$.

---

I don't know which is the regular definition people use. And also, I'm not sure whether this two versions of definition differs in some tricky circumstance, just like the "open set" mentioned above.

Comment: I'd say for your first compactness definition that "$E$ is compact in $X$" (with the metric $d$) or "$E$ is a compact subset of $X$". Then your second one amounts to saying that $X$ is compact in $X$, which we shorten to "$X$ is compact."

Comment: In some books I've read people define compact spaces. Then $E \subset X$ is compact set if $E$ is compact in the subspace topology. As @JohnHughes suggests, you could go other way around also. I don't think it makes a huge difference, since you always end up with equivalent concepts.

Comment: There's no real difference. A subset of a space can be regarded as a space in its own right since the parent space induces the topology on the subset. Also, it is meaningless to say that "$E$ is compact in $X$". The reason is that $E$ is either compact or not, all on its own, regardless of the fact that it lies in $X$. Implicit here is the fact that $E$ has a topology induced from $X$. $$ $$You may be thinking of similar usage of "$E$ is closed in $X$", where it *does* make a difference what the containing space is.

Comment: I suspect the word "set" is used because the first time most people encounter the concept is usually real analysis, and the notion that a subset is also a "subspace" is not initially brought up. Since, in real analysis, you are usually just dealing with one common class of metric spaces, we just avoid confusion. The definition for "$E$ is a compact subset of $X$" is the same as the definition of "$E$, given the subspace topology inherited from $X$, is a compact space."

Comment: Since no one has yet mentioned this, I'll point out that in topology the phrase [*absolute property*](https://www.google.com/search?q=topology+%22absolute+property%22) is used for properties such as compactness that hold regardless of what larger space the original space is a subspace of, with the original space being given the subspace topology it inherits from the larger space. Note that "larger space" could be the space itself. The property of being closed is not absolute -- note that $(0,1)$ is closed in the space $(0,1),$ closed in the space $(0,1) \cup \{2\},$ and not closed in $[0,1].$